# bundler throws user_interaction.rb:534:in 'initialize': No such file or directory - nul (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

After updating to rubygems 1.5.0, I get this error message when trying to run bundle install.

I am running on a cygwin environment with ruby 1.8.7 and bundler v 1.0.10

bundler throws user_interaction.rb:534:in 'initialize': No such file or directory - nul (Errno::ENOENT)

Can't really figure out what is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also having the same problem, I'm running rubygems 1.5.0, ruby 1.9.2, and bundler 1.0.10, on cygwin, and any time I try to run bundle I get the same error.

Actually, I just figured it out.  I'm assuming you are running Cygwin too, as here's the code that's causing the problem:

(in .../user_interaction.rb:534)

```
if Gem.win_platform?
  reader = File.open('nul', 'r')
  writer = File.open('nul', 'w')
else
  reader = File.open('/dev/null', 'r')
  writer = File.open('/dev/null', 'w')
end
```

See, it thinks you're using windows, when actually you are using linux within Cygwin.  So just comment out everything EXCEPT the two lines `reader = File.open('/dev/null', 'r')` and `writer = File.open('/dev/null/, /w/)`, and you should be good.

Obviously this is a rough fix, but does the trick as long as you aren't running the same installation of rubygems on windows natively.

Comment: A bugfix for this has already been submitted to RubyGems, it just hasn't been pushed out yet.

Comment: Hey thanks for that, I was just about to post the same thing and you beat me to it =).

Comment: Any idea when this is getting pushed?